# Json Exercise to dictionary using python

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, dictionary

I'm doing a course and I'm a little complicated with this exercise

I have 2 json that I have to join in a dictionary, but this must meet certain rules.

```
department = [
 {"ID": 1, "Name": "John", "Role": "Manager", "employees" :[
 {"ID": 4, "Name": "Mike", "Role": "Engineer"}]},
 {"ID": 3, "Name": "Sam", "Role": "Manager", "employees" :[]
 }]
employee = { "ID": [2],"Name": "Jack", "Role": "Analyst"}
```

1- The employee of Identifier 2 is under the charge of the Manager with Identifier 3.

2- The Database where the information will be ingested does not support columns of different data types.
To do this, a function must be generated that corrects this in the inputs.

3- The expected output must be a nested dictionary

How can I manage to join these fulfilling all conditions?

And the expected result should be this:

[image]

Comment: Who is the employee of identifier 2?

Comment: Can you give your desire output json ?

Comment: I just added the desire output, it should be nested dictionary

Answer (score 0):

You can update your json directly as:

```
department[1]['employees'].append(employee)
department

#output
    [{'ID': 1,
  'Name': 'John',
  'Role': 'Manager',
  'employees': [{'ID': 4, 'Name': 'Mike', 'Role': 'Engineer'}]},
 {'ID': 3,
  'Name': 'Sam',
  'Role': 'Manager',
  'employees': [{'ID': [2], 'Name': 'Jack', 'Role': 'Analyst'}]}]
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe the best way to do it is:

```
department[1]['employees'].append(employee)
```

Answer (score 0):

Because other employee IDs are integers (not lists), you need to extract the first item from the "ID" key to fix the input data.

You can use the next function (or a loop) to find department 3's dictionary in the list (hard coding the position in the list seemed like cheating to me)

Then append the whole employee dictionary to the "employees" list in department 3

```
employee["ID"] = employee["ID"][0]                        # fix employee ID
department3 = next(d for d in department if d["ID"] == 3) # find department 3
department3["employees"].append(employee)                 # add employee
```

result:

```
import json
print(json.dumps(department,indent=2))

[
  {
    "ID": 1,
    "Name": "John",
    "Role": "Manager",
    "employees": [
      {
        "ID": 4,
        "Name": "Mike",
        "Role": "Engineer"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "ID": 3,
    "Name": "Sam",
    "Role": "Manager",
    "employees": [
      {
        "ID": 2,
        "Name": "Jack",
        "Role": "Analyst"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

> 2- *The Database where the information will be ingested does not support columns of different data types. To do this, a function must be generated that corrects this in the inputs.*

You could use a function like this to enforce datatypes:

```py
def format_empData(val, key, enforce=False, defaultVal=None):
    if key == 'ID':
        try: return int(val[0] if val and isinstance(val, list) else val)
        except: return defaultVal if enforce else val
    return str(val)
```

---

> 1- *The employee of Identifier 2 is under the charge of the Manager with Identifier 3.*

You can loop through the departments until you find the right one and then add `employee` after processing each value in it with `format_empData`:

```py
managerId = 3
for di, dept in enumerate(department):
    if dept['ID'] == managerId:
        department[di]['employees'].append(
            {k: format_empData(v, k) for k, v in employee.items()})
        break
```

After that, `department` should look like

> ```py
> [{'ID': 1, 'Name': 'John', 'Role': 'Manager',
>   'employees': [{'ID': 4, 'Name': 'Mike', 'Role': 'Engineer'}]},
>  {'ID': 3, 'Name': 'Sam', 'Role': 'Manager',
>   'employees': [{'ID': 2, 'Name': 'Jack', 'Role': 'Analyst'}]}]
> ```